# Can't get XPATH working with Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrape the "Today's featured article" on Wikipedia by getting the XPATH value using firebug.

[image]

And then pasting it into my code:

```
string result = wc.DownloadString("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

            doc.LoadHtml(result);

            var featuredArticle = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/p");
```

However, featuredArticle always returns null.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Firebug may show html modified by scripts but you are loading an original server html.

Answer (score 2):

Because what Firebug shows the XPath like Firefox made the Html, that may or may not be what the Html from the server is. Also, the Path from Firebug is absolute, and every little change can break it.

And easier way is to just look at the Html, the p-Tag you are looking for is in a div with the id `mp-tfa`, so it's easier to make the XPath look for the div and the just get the first p inside.

Like this:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(wc.OpenRead("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"));
var featuredArticle = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='mp-tfa']/p");
Console.WriteLine(featuredArticle.InnerText);
```

The best place to learn how to use XPath is [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

Or you could use Linq, though i feel XPath is a bit more clear.

```
var featuredArticle=   doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
 .First(n => n.Id == "mp-tfa")
 .Descendants("p").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This points me in the right direction, and helps in this particular case, but what if I'm trying to scrape a website that doesn't always have id's for every element? Wouldn't I be pretty much forced to use xpath?

Comment: well, you can check every other attribute of the element you want to get, using both xpath and linq. can you post the site or some part of the structure you want to parse? that'd make it a bit easier to help :)