# HtmlAgilityPack & XPath produce 2 differents results

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I don't understand what's the difference in this code between birthdateNode2 & birthdateNode3.
[image: HtmlAgilityPack C# code.]

1. On this case :
   [image: Html inspect of new file]
   I'm able to get the birth date with 'birthdateNode3'. (birthdateNode2 is null).
   **Why birthdateNode2 & birthdateNode3 don't point on the same location ?**
2. On this other case, the html is older and structure is a bit different. The birth date is not specified. birthdateNode2 is null. birthdateNode3 points on 'p' but on the next .
   [image: Html inspect of older file]
   **Why nor birthdateNode2 & birthdateNode3 aren't null because there's no birthdate specified ?**

Thanks for help.
Vincent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get XPATH working with Html Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871451/cant-get-xpath-working-with-html-agility-pack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `birthdateNode2` you are selecting the ChildNodes of the `li` element, and then selecting downwards from there to select a `p` element - so you are always going down two levels from the `li` (remember `p` is short for `child::p`). With `birthdateNode3` you are only going down one level.

Comment: Thanks it works now :). I've changed a bit my code 
HtmlNode birthdateNode2 = rowNode
                .Descendants()
                .Where(n => n.InnerText == "Né(e) le")
                .First();
HtmlNode birthdateNode3 = birthdateNode2.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode("p");
birthDate = birthdateNode3?.InnerText.Trim();